# How to store a message with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a similar problem which is already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125320/how-to-edit-a-react-component-and-change-the-text-displayed-on-screen)

I have the same code.

When I write a message and then I click on my 'edit' button, I have a problem with this line :

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.editMethod(this.state.inputValue)}>edit</button>
```

Concretely, I want to be able to write a message and that it remains even if we leave the browser but we can change it at any time thanks to the edit button. Should we use the Local Storage ?

Comment: Local Storage sounds like a valid solution. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423108/using-localstorage-with-react).

Comment: If the things you are storing are big, better use IndexedDB which is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is a perfect option if you don't need the text to show cross browser or on older browsers where you don't have local storage.

If you need cross browser and more universal solution, you might want to bring in a backend. Where you'll sync the message on edit. And fetch the message on load.